# $\mathcal{M, N}$ are $\sigma$-algebras. Prove that $\mathcal{M \setminus N}$ also is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Could you tell me why if $\mathcal{M, N}$ are $\sigma$-algebras, then $\mathcal{M \setminus N}$ also is a $\sigma$-algebra?

I've just started reading about measure theory, but I don't think it can be true, because bu subtracting $\mathcal{N}$ from $\mathcal{M}$ we lose all common properties of $\sigma$ -algebras. Is my reasoning wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ are $\sigma$-algebras, then $\mathcal{M} \setminus \mathcal{N}$ is *never* a $\sigma$-algebra.

For instance, every $\sigma$-algebra contains the empty set.  Therefore, $\mathcal{M} \setminus \mathcal{N}$ never does.

Where did you find this claim?